ASSOCIATE YITH BRAND WITH PRODUCT
Brands:
I am using Yith Woocommerce Brands to upload the brands.


ERP:
The store is connected to my ERP and it is this that sends the information to Woocommerce using Custom Metas. In this case there is a Meta Term "Brand".

I want to associate the Yith brand with this meta so that it is automatically placed on the product.

Please open a ticket with YITH and whatever service connects to your ERP.  Both are third party and you'll get more help from them than you will here because they're third-party services/plugins/themes and that means that the vast majority of WP developers probably have no clue how their built.
